# UINavigationBar Not Visible With UITabBarController

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trying to construct a tableview with a navigation bar at top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990915/trying-to-construct-a-tableview-with-a-navigation-bar-at-top)

I have got a `UITabBarController` with a `TabBar` in it. Now what I need is a `UINavigationBar` on top of controller just to show title and a button. For that, I have taken a stand alone `UINavigationBar`, but it is not visible I can't understand why.

I am sorry but haven't found any appropriate solution up till now. Is there any specific way to use and access stand alone `UINavigationBar` with `UITabBarController`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Following link worked for me perfectly!

[Trying to construct a tableview with a navigation bar at top](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6991026/437146)

Answer (score 1):

Create your UIViewControllers and there views using Interface Builder or coding to be displayed in each of the Tabs. Add the NavigationBar to each one of these views.

Then add these UIViewControllers to the UITabViewController's viewControllers NSArray.

ie. In you AppDelegate's application didFinishLaunching function

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Add the UINavigationBar to the viewController1 and viewControllers2 views, either using IB or coding it.

Comment: Thanks alot Wextux for quick reply. I tried your technique but it didnot work for me. Sorry.